# Linear classifier with PyTorch from scratch questions

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to implement linear classifier in PyTorch, using 1 layer with tensors `W` and `b`, softmax and cross entropy loss. For each batch I have to:

1. Calculate logits
2. Transform logits to probabilities with softmax
3. Compute most probable classes
4. Calculate cross entropy between true and predicted classes
5. Use an optimizer to change `W` and `b`

So far I have (I have flat MNIST loaded with Scikit-learn):

```
# convert Numpy arrays to PyTorch tensor Variables
input_X_train = torch.from_numpy(X_train_flat).float().to(device)
input_X_val = torch.from_numpy(X_val_flat).float().to(device)
input_X_test = torch.from_numpy(X_test_flat).float().to(device)

input_y_train = torch.from_numpy(y_train).long().to(device)
input_y_val = torch.from_numpy(y_val).long().to(device)
input_y_test = torch.from_numpy(y_test).long().to(device)

# model parameters: W and b
W = torch.randn(input_dim, output_dim, device=device, dtype=dtype, requires_grad=True)
b = torch.randn(1, device=device, dtype=dtype, requires_grad=True)

BATCH_SIZE = 512
EPOCHS = 40
LEARNING_RATE = 1e-6

# create torch.optim.Adam optimizer for loss function minimization
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([W, b], lr=LEARNING_RATE)

# create negative log loss function object for loss function evaluation
# use mean loss value from all batch samples
loss_fn = torch.nn.NLLLoss(reduction="mean")

for t in range(EPOCHS):    
    # logits for input_X, resulting shape should be [input_X.shape[0], 10]
    logits = torch.matmul(input_X_train, W) + b

    # apply torch.nn.functional.softmax (torch_F.softmax) to logits
    probas = torch_f.softmax(logits, dim=1)
    
    # apply torch.argmax to find a class index with highest probability
    classes = torch.argmax(probas, dim=1)

    # loss should be a scalar number: average loss over all the objects with torch.mean()
    # PyTorch implements negative log loss (NLL) *without* log - you have to first compute log of 
    # softmax, then negative log loss, which will swap sign
    
    # Use torch.nn.functional.log_softmax (torch_f.log_softmax) on top of input_y and logits
    # It is identical to calculating cross-entropy (log and then NLL) on top of probas, 
    # but is more numerically friendly (read the docs).
    log_probas = torch_f.log_softmax(logits, dim=1)
    loss = loss_fn(log_probas, input_y_train)

    # Before the backward pass, use the optimizer object to zero all of the
    # gradients for the variables it will update (which are the learnable
    # weights of the model). This is because by default, gradients are
    # accumulated in buffers( i.e, not overwritten) whenever .backward()
    # is called. Checkout docs of torch.autograd.backward for more details.
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    # calculate backward gradients for backpropagation
    loss.backward()
    
    # Calling the step function on an Optimizer makes an update to its parameters
    optimizer.step()
```

For some reason, the `W` and `b` don't change. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I've seen and tried in the code above e. g. this minimal working example https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/minimal-working-example-of-optim-sgd/11623/2.

EDIT 2:
Gradients `W.grad` are often, I think it should not be like that. Probabilities of classes are definitely right (so it's not e. g. like [this example](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-parameterss-gradient-is-zero/12617/3)), since I've checked sum of every row and probabilities of all classes for each sample sum to 1.

Comment: There are typos in your code so I can't run it, but your issue seems to be that your learning rate is too small for a linear classifier. Try something like a learning rate of 0.01.

Comment: @jodag I've fixed the typos, but yeah, you're right, after further testing it seems that network is working, the LR was so low it looked like it wasn't training.